# footable on nested repeater adds comma in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, responsive-design

I have a repeater inside a repeater (that is nested repeater) and applied foo table on it. problem is , when foo table is applied on the repeater (that is , when it is in tablet or cell phone format) a comma is added in textbox. eg: if I enter "empty" in textbox it shows as ",empty" . if i remove ",empty" and add "empty1" then it will show ",empty1,emtpy" in textbox. when i open the page in desktop or laptop view no commas are inserted , even if they are inserted in tablet and cell phone view on resizing them to desktop commas disappear. It is because of footable . tried a lot but didnot find the solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase if someone still searching for the similar issue here is the [link](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/issues/64) to the ticket I opened on footable project. Bradvin fixed the issue I think it should not create problem in the new version of footable.